# Force scrollview to re-render when closing a react-navigation modal?

Tags: react-native, realm, react-navigation

I'm opening a modal, nested in a react-navigation TabNavigator.
This modal is used to add, say a teammate, to a Realm database.
When the new teammate is saved, I close the modal and "navigate" back to a ScrollView displaying all the teammates, retrieved from my Realm database.

My problem is that this ScrollView doesn't re-render when closing the modal.

I am not using Redux or any other state manager.

This is the code executed when saving a user:

```
    onButtonPress() {
    var teammate = new TeammateModel(this.firstname, this.lastname);
    if (this.firstname && this.lastname) {
        TeammateService.save(teammate);
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
    } 
}
```

And this is the code of the for the component rendering the ScrollView:

```
export default class Team extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
    teammates = TeammateService.findAll();
}

render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <List>{teammates.map((teammate) => (
            <ListItem 
                key={teammate.id}
                title={`${teammate.firstname} ${teammate.lastname}`}
            />
            ))}
            </List>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
}
```

As requested here's also my routes.js where the navigation happens:

```
export const TeamStack = StackNavigator({
Team: {
    screen: Team,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: 'Team',
        headerRight: <Button title="Add" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EditTeammate')} />
    }),
},
})

export const EditTeammateStack = StackNavigator({
EditTeammate: {
    screen: EditTeammate,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: 'Teammate',
        headerLeft: <Button title="Cancel" onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />
    }),
}
})


export const NoteStack = StackNavigator({
EditNote: {
    screen: EditNote,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: 'Edit note'
    })
}
})

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({

EditNote: {
    screen: NoteStack,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: { visible: true },
        headerTitle: 'Edit note',
        tabBarLabel: 'Notes',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={20} color={tintColor} />
    }),
},
Team: {
    screen: TeamStack,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: { visible: true },
        headerTitle: 'Team',
        tabBarLabel: 'Team',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="users" size={20} color={tintColor} />
    }),
}
}, {
initialRouteName: 'Team',
});
```

export const Root = StackNavigator({
    Tabs: {
        screen: Tabs,
    },
    EditTeammate: {
        screen: EditTeammateStack,
    },
}, {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
});

export default Root;

I'm sure I'm doing one (or more) thing(s) wrong. But what? :)

Comment: Could you give more information on your setup? Your code does not show your modal code. Is your modal nested in the main component? Are you using redux?

Comment: @nonsequiter Just added the routes.js where the navigation happens. Hope it helps! I'm not using any state manager at the moment.